# Concatenate fields using connect by prior

Tags: oracle, string-aggregation

Having the following table `my_tabe`:

```
M01 |   1
M01 |   2
M02 |   1
```

I want to query over it in order to obtain:

```
M01 |   1,2
M02 |   1
```

I managed to get close using the following query:

```
with my_tabe as
(
    select 'M01' as scycle, '1' as sdate from dual union
    select 'M01' as scycle, '2' as sdate from dual union
    select 'M02' as scycle, '1' as sdate from dual
)
SELECT scycle, ltrim(sys_connect_by_path(sdate, ','), ',')
FROM
(
    select scycle, sdate, rownum rn
    from my_tabe
    order by 1 desc
)
START WITH rn = 1
CONNECT BY PRIOR rn = rn - 1
```

Yielding:

```
SCYCLE      |   RES
M02         |   1,2,1
M01         |   1,2
```

Which is wrong. It's seems I'm close, but I'm afraid I don't what's the next step...

Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to restrict your `connect by` to the same `scycle` value, and also count the number of matches and filter on that to avoid seeing intermediate results.

```
with my_tabe as
(
    select 'M01' as scycle, '1' as sdate from dual union
    select 'M01' as scycle, '2' as sdate from dual union
    select 'M02' as scycle, '1' as sdate from dual
)
select scycle, ltrim(sys_connect_by_path(sdate, ','), ',')
from
(
    select distinct sdate,
        scycle,
        count(1) over (partition by scycle) as cnt,
        row_number() over (partition by scycle order by sdate) as rn
    from my_tabe
)
where rn = cnt
start with rn = 1
connect by prior rn + 1 = rn
and prior scycle = scycle
/

SCYCLE LTRIM(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(SDATE,','),',')
------ -----------------------------------------
M01    1,2
M02    1
```

If you're on 11g you can use the built-in [`LISTAGG`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/functions087.htm) function instead:

```
with my_tabe as
(
    select 'M01' as scycle, '1' as sdate from dual union
    select 'M01' as scycle, '2' as sdate from dual union
    select 'M02' as scycle, '1' as sdate from dual
)
select scycle, listagg (sdate, ',') 
within group (order by sdate) res
from my_tabe
group by scycle
/
```

Both approaches (and others) are shown [here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_display_multiple_column_values_same_rows.htm).